# Meaningful way to use Dimensional Reduction and Euclidean Distance for clustering variables?

Tags: pca, dimensionality-reduction, hierarchical-clustering

How do I find the hierarchical interrelationships between variables after dimensional reduction since PCA dimensional reduction is sensitive to the ordering of the columns in source data?

I made a test input file p=30 and n=569 from a pre-made dataset

```
from sklearn.datasets import load_breast_cancer
cancer = load_breast_cancer()
cancer.keys()

df = pd.DataFrame(cancer['data'],columns=cancer['feature_names'])
df.to_csv(r'input file',index=False)
```

Then I applied a PCA transformation on the covariance matrix and reduced the n=30 dimensions to n=4 since just 4 components are needed to explain 99.9% of the variance. Then I tried to find the hierarchical relationships between variables. I found the pairwise euclidean distance between each variable with the other variables. The euclidean distance used each of the 4 PCA components for every variable in feature space.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

daily_series = pd.read_csv (r'input path')

sd = daily_series[daily_series.columns[0:daily_series.shape[1]]]
scaled_data = sd #unscaled
from sklearn.decomposition import PCA
pca = PCA(n_components=daily_series.shape[1])
pca_model = pca.fit(scaled_data)
components = ['PC1','PC2','PC3','PC4','PC5','PC6','PC7','PC8','PC9','PC10','PC11','PC12','PC13','PC14','PC15','PC16','PC17','PC18','PC19','PC20','PC21','PC22','PC23','PC24','PC25','PC26','PC27','PC28','PC29','PC30']
variables = daily_series.columns[0:daily_series.shape[1]]
Matrix = pd.DataFrame(pca_model.components_, columns=components, index=variables)

Matrix.to_csv(r'output path', index=True)

red_components = ['PC1','PC2','PC3','PC4']

distance = np.asmatrix([[np.NaN for i in range(cols)] for j in range(cols)])
distance_norm = np.asmatrix([[np.NaN for i in range(cols)] for j in range(cols)])

red_Matrix = Matrix[red_components]

for i in range(0,cols):
    for j in range(0,cols):
        a = np.asarray(red_Matrix.iloc[i,:])
        b = np.asarray(red_Matrix.iloc[j,:])
        distance[i,j] = math.sqrt(sum([(a[k]-b[k]) ** 2 for k in range(len(b))]))

for i in range(0,cols):
    for j in range(0,cols):
        distance_norm[i,j] = distance[i,j]/np.max(distance)*100

Distance = pd.DataFrame(distance_norm, columns=variables, index=variables)
Distance = np.transpose(Distance)
Distance.columns = variables
Distance.to_csv(r'distanceoutput path')
```

Cluster without dimensional reduction (30/30 components):
[image]

Clusters with dimensional reduction (4/30 components):
[image]

Clusters with dimensional reduction (4/30 components) with different ordering of columns in source data: 
[image]

Clearly dimensional reduction is necessary. And clearly the order of the columns is impacting the results so my clusters (made with Ward 2 method in R) are not reliable. How can I cluster the variables in a way that reflects interrelationships between variables?

Comment: I'm not really clear on what you're doing in the latter part of your post. Is there a way that you can express you think column order is important that doesn't depend on distance computations and clustering? Using SVD to make an orthogonal projection of $A$ is not changed by a column permutation, which makes me think that the error lies with a different part of your reasoning, unrelated to PCA. Observe that $$AP = USV^\top P \implies APP^\top V = AV = US$$

Comment: Also, this claim "PCA dimensional reduction is sensitive to the ordering of the columns in source data" is ... not correct. I showed in your previous post that the permutation of the input amounts to the permutation of $V^\top$. And my comment shows that after using $V$ to rotate $A$, you end up with a matrix that has linearly independent columns and cares not at all about permutation. I must conclude that the answer is "your program isn't doing what you want" but I'm not clear on how to create a unit test for what you want, so this question doesn't really seem answerable in the SE format.

Comment: My best guess is that what you actually want to do is use `pca.transform(scaled_data)` instead of `pca.components_` but that's meeting you more than half-way.

Comment: @SycoraxsaysReinstateMonica There are 30! possible arrangements of columns for A (source data). The column order arrangement in A is important because it changes which 4 components are considered for the distance calculation.

Comment: I agree. That's why I think you are actually interested in $AV$ and not $V$.

Comment: @SycoraxsaysReinstateMonica AV has the same dimensions as A which no longer abstracts away the p number of samples

Comment: Do you mean "features" in place of "samples"? The typical PCA usage is to reduce the number of features (columns), so we use a truncated $V$ denoted as $V_k$ to give the $k$ components with largest variation via $AV_k$: each sample is summarized in $k$ columns, so $AV_k$ has shape `(n_samples, k)`.

Comment: @SycoraxsaysReinstateMonica p is number of features. n is number of samples. $AV_k$ is n x k but how would that help identify relationships between p features after dimensional reduction? It's not possible to do distance calculations if the p-k features are abstracted away...

Comment: I think the better way to ask this question is to focus on what you want to achieve (know relationships among features), not the procedure you're using to achieve it (pca, distance computations, clustering). In other words, I think this post is an XY problem. http://xyproblem.info/ Right now, you're blocked by an obstacle about PCA, but I'm not convinced that solving your real question needs to use PCA at all.

Comment: Ok let's say the n samples actually form a time series like weather data for example and I want to cluster all features based on patterns over the same time window. Are you suggesting PCA+Euclidean Distance can't help me accomplish this? What are other methods I can try? If this is a non-redundant question I can post another question.

Comment: Time series analysis seems like a very different problem than the classification problem in the breast cancer setting. I would ask a new question which is specific to what you know. We have more information about how to ask a good question in [help] and meta.stats.SE is a good place to ask about how this site works and to get feedback on questions.

Comment: This is first and foremost a classification problem. It isn't specific to a particular setting. If the breast cancer samples are taken at regular time intervals (simplest case) then it doesn't affect the interrelationships between features which is what I'd like to find "how do I find the hierarchical interrelationships between variables" Would it be meaningful to average the C(30,4)= 30k distance matrices?

Comment: I'm not convinced that any part of this process is a good solution to finding hierarchical interrelationships between variables. If you want to know how to find hierarchical interrelationships between variables, why not just ask about that? Right now, your post says that a hammer isn't working correctly because it's not good at turning screws. Why not just ask if there's a better way to turn screws?